# Cisco 2960-S switch with MAB and Packetfence Web Authentication

Tags: cisco, network-access, aaa, ieee-802.1x

I am trying to set up Packetfence In my corporate environment for guest users, with MAC access bypass. i have done everything like in the official Packetfence installation guide https://packetfence.org/doc/PacketFence_Installation_Guide.html#_getting_started .
802.1X with RADIUS VLAN enforcement working fine, but MAB with Web Authentication not showing Captive Portal. I am using the same interface as a management and portal. This management interface is in the same VLAN as the switch management interface, eg. VLANID is 2. i am using Cisco Catalyst 2960-S and using IOS 15. Portal is accessible from workstation from VLAN 3 which is connected on an access port which is not doing 802.1X, or MAB on the http://PF_MANAGEMENT_IP/captive-portal , but not accessible from a machine which is doing MAB authentication. I have on a switch registration ACL defined per instructions from the guide:

```
ip access-list extended registration
    deny ip any host PF_MANAGEMENT_IP
    permit tcp any any eq www
    permit tcp any any eq 443
```

And added role by switch role to registration name of this ACL, and also role by Web Authentication registration URL:
http://PF_MANAGEMENT_IP/Cisco::Catalyst_2960

When I test this, with a supplicant it gets the right VLAN 3 which I defined as a registration, and browser pop-ups with a http://www.msftconnecttest.com/redirect url which is at the end change with http://PF_MANAGEMENT_IP/Cisco::Catalyst_2960 but connection time put in browser. I even tried explicitly to access that url but without success. Just to mention that supplicant gets the right IP/subnet DHCP and DNS, which are my production DHCP and DNS. But I can not get it to open Captive Portal. Also I have set on switch:

```
ip device tracking
ip http server
ip secure-server
```

I have checked packetfence.log and communication there is ok, no errors, right VLAN assigned. Also checked radius.log and all communication is right. Also I checked http.portal log and there is no log, except I am seeing that supplicant is not touching portal during registration, which is obvious.
I think the problem lies somewhere between Cisco switch redirection and portal. but I do not have anymore idea how to troubleshoot it.
if you need switch epm debug log feel free to request but to me that does not seem erroneous but I am not expert at this.

This is partial switch configuration which is relevant for dot1x, mab. I am doing this from head, as currently I do not have access to that switch:

```
dot1x system-auth-control
aaa new-model
aaa group server radius packetfence
    server PF_MANAGEMENT_IP auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authentication dot1x default group packetfence
aaa authorization network default group packetfence
radius-server host PF_MANAGEMENT_IP auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 timeout 2 key ExampleSecret
radius-server vsa send authentication
snmp-server community mysnmp RO
snmp-server community myWritesnmp RW


interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/1
   switchport mode access
   authentication host-mode single-host
   authentication order dot1x mab
   authentication priority dot1x mab
   authentication port-control auto
   authentication periodic
   authentication timer restart 10800
   authentication timer reauthenticate 10800
   mab
   no snmp trap link-status
   dot1x pae authenticator
   dot1x timeout quiet-period 2
   dot1x timeout tx-period 3

aaa server radius dynamic-author
   client PF_MANAGEMENT_IP server-key ExampleSecret
   port 3799

ip device tracking
ip http server
ip http secure-server

ip access-list extended registration
   deny ip any host PF_MANAGEMENT_IP
   permit tcp any any eq www
   permit tcp any any eq 443
```

As you can see I am using just one port Gi1/0/1 for the testing. Two VLANs are relevant in my setup:
VLAN ID 2:
PF_MANAGEMENT_IP -> PacketFence management interface and captive portal interface ip is in this VLAN.
SWITCH_MGMT_IP -> Switch management IP is in this VLAN.

VLAN ID 3:
TEST_WORKSTATION_IP -> supplicant IP address is in this VLAN.

VLAN ID 4: production DHCP and DNS are in this VLAN.

There are no restrictions/ACLs which prevents communication between these VLANs. VLAN management is done from the L3 Switch, and network architecture is collapsed core, where access switch is this switch which is used for testing.

Comment: The permit statements will never be matched to the server because the deny will match everything to the server and the ACL will exit on the deny match.

Comment: just take into account that this access list is not set onto interface statically it is assigned on the interface doing aaa dynamically. I thought also that is the case, but than I have read the Cisco ISE to enlighten me how this redirection works, and it says that that deny means not to pass the request to the CPU, and permit means that this request needs to be passed to the CPU for more processing, where epm intercepts this request and doing redirection. and indeed I have tested without that but then forcing redirection will not work

Comment: An ACL is tested top down, and it exits on the first match. A deny will cause the packet to be dropped. You need to give us more information. Please edit your question to include the full switch configuration.

Comment: Everything explained here https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/identity-services-engine/117278-troubleshoot-ise-00.html  and here https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ibns/configuration/15-e/ibns-15-e-book/ibns-webauth-origin-url.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjLi63up-jdAhXO6qQKHT4ZChAQFjAGegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2qvIfR0ggBTJW-IddlkQK6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't succeeded to achieve this via switch Web Authentication facility, but I have achieved this via Packetfence registration VLAN and dns black holling. I have created registration VLAN on cisco switch which is not routed. Achieved this by not creating SVI for that VLAN, and not adding ip helper-address. After that I have created Registration interface on packetfence in this VLAN and added Packetfence dhcpd service to listen on it and assign ip addresses to nodes. This way Packetfence will assign ip address to new nodes and pass them Packetfence DNS server ip and using dns sinkhole technique will force to register using portal.

Comment: You shoulc accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.